# File upload app is stuck

Tags: c#, file, upload, ftpwebrequest

If I run my program and strUploadIP doens't exits in my network my whole application is stuck

```
  FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo(strFile);
                    FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + **strUploadIP** + @"/" + strUser);
                    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUusername, strUpassword);
                    try
                    {
                        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
                        }
                    }
```

how can I get to try catch this or something?

Comment: huh? I don't understand your question?

Comment: I doubt this is all code of the class/methode, since you already have a *try* statement, but without a *catch* or *finally* it isn't valid C#. Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a try/catch to handle any errors.

```
    FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + **strUploadIP** + @"/" + strUser);
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUusername, strUpassword);
    try {
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        }
    } catch {
        // TODO: Handle exception
    }
```